# VBA sheet1 equation output into sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a function which is able to transform a date into a number value. I plan to find the difference in these values to find the time between two events. txt values are simply text boxes in a userform sheet.

`WS.Cells(row, column) = (txtYear.Value * 365) + (txtMonth.Value * 30) + (txtDay.Value)`

To keep the sheet clean, I plan to log the resulting values into a separate worksheet, with any equations involving said data occurring in this second sheet and ideally being sent back to sheet one.

I realise it is possible to copy cell values from one sheet to another using `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Test:Test").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("Test")`, however I am trying to skip the step involving copying data from a cell for the sake on cleanliness, and instead have my calculated data sent directly to the second worksheet.

Any help will be appreciated!
(row, column, test values are simply listed as such for reading sake, and will have distinct values in the real function)

EDIT: In the meantime, I have been logging the output value into a miscellaneous cell, and then trying to copy the cell value into worksheet 2

`WS.Cells(2, 20) = (txtYear.Value * 365) + (txtMonth.Value * 30) + (txtDay.Value) ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range(intRow, intCol) = Sum([Sheet1]!T2)`

However I have been receiving an error "Sub of function not defined" in the 'Sum' part of the second line. I have written similar functions using Sum, so I am a bit clueless to why it does not work now. (intRow and intCol are variables to determine the cell used)

Comment: Note that a date in Excel is already a number value. So you should probably be using `DateSerial(txtYear.Value, txtMonth.Value, txtDay.Value)` to return a valid date, not doing the math yourself (which by the way is off as it assumes all months have 30 days, does not handle leap years, etc.)

Comment: In the spirit of _Any help will be appreciated_ I'd say abandon what you are doing.  Both your stated aims (dates to numbers and date diff) already exist in both Excel formulas and VBA.

Comment: Im still very new to VBA, so I am still uncertain of the capabilities of excel. I will look to change my date-to-value function in the future. At the moment I am only concerned with getting the function to work, shortening my code will come later.

Comment: What Chris is saying is, you're on the wrong road. Don't go down it any further. It doesn't work, and it won't work. As regards your edit, the sum of a single number is itself. There is no need to sum anything here.

Comment: `Range(intRow, intCol)` should be `Cells(intRow, intCol)`

Comment: Fair enough, I will look to change my function. I am still curious about the feasibility of having an output value recorded into a separate sheet, though.

Comment: Value assignment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(intRow, intCol).Value = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you validate any user input before using it.

```vb
Sub GetDate()
   
   Dim y As Integer, m As Integer, d As Integer
   y = Val(txtYear.Value)
   m = Val(txtMonth.Value)
   d = Val(txtDate.Value)
   If (y > 2000) And _
       (m >= 1 And m <= 12) And _
       (d >= 1 And d <= 31) Then
       WS.Cells(2, 20) = DateSerial(y, m, d)
   Else
       MsgBox "Invalid date " & d & "/" & m & "/" & y, vbExclamation
   End If
   
End Sub
```